# Magento 2 checkout "New Address" Button remove for some customers?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, onestepcheckout

Magento 2 on the checkout Page "**New Address**" button. How can I add a conditional to this button for some users?

I need to hide this button for some customers **if my condition is true**

[image]

Comment: I got a alternative solution with JavaScript and css but its not a final solution :)

Comment: Hey surender I tried on this very hard. I too came to conclusion of one and only way to be using JS. Yet, I would love to see your answer. What I did was extending/overriding shiping.js. What is your way?

Comment: I have put a javascript  in onepage.phtml 
Eg:

`<?php if(condition true){  ?>
 <script>  
  require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
   $(document).ready(function($) { 
    
     jQuery("#customsuren").remove(); 
            jQuery("#sameaddress").remove();  
  
   });
               });
  </script>
   
<?php  }  ?>`

Comment: That was simple and nice logic , mine was quite complicated. I tried to do it by overriding shipping.js file and had to do hard work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put this code at onepage.phtml
Ids mention according you.

```
<?php if(condition true){ ?> 
     <script> 
        require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], 
         function($){ 
          $(document).ready(function($) {  
             jQuery("#id").remove(); 
             jQuery("#id").remove();
             }); 
          }); 
     </script>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a requirement to remove the **New Address** button from the shipping address and billing address from shipping and Payment steps respectfully based on a flag that was set in the customerData.
To achieve this, we followed the given approach:

Override the JS and template files from **vendor/magento/module-checkout/** module to your theme folder and follow the steps given below:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js
>   [around Line no. 75]

**Add new line at: Line no. 30**

```
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
```

**Add new line at: Line no. 53**

```
shippingRateService,
customerData
```

**Now customerData is accessible.**

**Add new line at: Line No. 68**

```
displayNewAddressPopup: customerData.get('restrict_addr'),
```

after addition of this line, the code should look like:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t,
    shippingRateService,
    customerData
) {
    'use strict';

    var popUp = null;

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping',
            shippingFormTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form',
            shippingMethodListTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-list',
            shippingMethodItemTemplate: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item'
        },
        visible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual()),
        errorValidationMessage: ko.observable(false),
        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn,
        isFormPopUpVisible: formPopUpState.isVisible,
        isFormInline: addressList().length === 0,
        isNewAddressAdded: ko.observable(false),
        saveInAddressBook: 1,
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),
        displayNewAddressPopup: customerData.get('zonal_prices')().win_id,
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
>   [around Line no. 18]

**Replace:**

```
<!-- Address form pop up -->
<if args="!isFormInline">
    <button type="button" class="action action-show-popup primary" click="showFormPopUp" visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
        <span translate="'New Address'" />
    </button>
    <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" visible="isFormPopUpVisible()" render="shippingFormTemplate" />
</if>
```

**With:**

```
<!-- Address form pop up -->
<if args="!isFormInline">
        <if args="!displayNewAddressPopup">
            <button type="button" class="action action-show-popup primary" click="showFormPopUp" visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                <span translate="'New Address'" />
            </button>
            <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" visible="isFormPopUpVisible()" render="shippingFormTemplate" />
        </if>
</if>
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/billing-address.js

**Add new line at: Line No. 68**

```
hideBillingAddressSwitcher: customerData.get('restrict_addr'),
```

after addition of this line, the code should look like:

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address'
    },
    currentBillingAddress: quote.billingAddress,
    addressOptions: addressOptions,
    customerHasAddresses: addressOptions.length > 1,
    hideBillingAddressSwitcher: customerData.get('restrict_addr'),
```

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address.html

**Replace:**

```
<div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
           data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
    <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span
            data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
</div>
```

**With:**

```
<if args="!hideBillingAddressSwitcher">
        <div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
            <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
                   data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
            <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span
                    data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
        </div>
</if>
```

This is how, based on the value **restrict_addr** stored in the **customerData**, we were able to hide the add new address buttons.

Note: To set the custom variable in the customerData, please refer this link: [Customer Data Management in Magento 2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwj_vYjK587fAhUCUI8KHXlKCVcQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbelvg.com%2Fblog%2Fcustomer-data-management-in-magento-2.html&usg=AOvVaw2aem23uHZjsn5elH0ddEsW)